# Count the number of trailing spaces of a text node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to get the number of trailing characters in a text node. I've thought of the following:

```
string-length(substring-after(.,substring(normalize-space(.), string-length(normalize-space(.)),1)))
```

E.g., the length of the substring after the final character.

Except, it doesn't work because [`substring-after`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256455%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return the *first* substring matching. For example, `substring-after('mississippi','i')` will return 'ssissippi'. I also can't match the entire normalized string, because it may contain double spaces that are removed and `substring-after`  will not match anymore.

Is there a way to get the number of trailing whitespaces in a string?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (in XSLT 1.0) other than by a recursive template. You can choose to loop over the trailing spaces or over the occurrences of the last two characters in the normalized string (depending on which do you expect less of). Note also that "spaces" is not the same thing as "whitespace characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\s*)$">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:sequence select="string-length(regex-group(1))"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course instead of writing a template matching text nodes you could write a function taking a string and then doing what I suggested

```
<xsl:function name="mf:count" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="(\s*)$">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:sequence select="string-length(regex-group(1))"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: I'll bump my version XSLT version from 1.0 to 2.0. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Oh, my processor doesn't support XSLT 2.0. :<